# fprintf after opening file using fopen does not work in matlab

Tags: matlab, printf, fopen

May be my tired eyes are ignoring something trivial. But I am not able to get the following code work in matlab. I need to open an existing file and write text to it.

```
filename='E:\\data_bak\\test.txt';
fileId=fopen(filename,'r+');
if(fileId~=-1)
    myline=fgetl(fileId);
    nbytes=fprintf(fileId,'%s\n','testdata')
    fclose(fileId);    
end
```

I am using matlab 7.9.0 on windows 7. I have tried rt+ for permissions in fopen. Also, fileId is not equal to zero as I am able to read the line in the variable myline. In addition, fprintf('%s\n','testdata') successfully prints testdata on the matlab prompt.

The value assigned to nbytes is 9. So it does appear it has written to file but when I open the file in text editor, I am not able to find text 'testdata'.

Comment: Have you tried `filename='E:\\data_bak\test.txt';` - without the second double-backslash?

Comment: That code works fine for me. Make sure you refresh the file in text editor. Is E a network drive or a local drive? Network drives might show some lag.

Comment: Just tried without the second backslash. Still does not work. Also, E is a local drive.

Comment: Workaround: create temporary file with w flag. Then copy entire content of original file to new file. Delete the original file and move the new file to original file. Still dont know why the original code fails.